# Long cold start delay for the first time app is installed when using the latest gradle 2.1.2, workaround?

Tags: android, gradle, delay, cold-start

So I've been noticing something strange when using the newest gradle(2.1.2) for building my apps, the first time the app is installed the cold start screen is dramatically long (10 to 30 seconds even), I thought it was odd and just changed the gradle version to 2.0.0 and tada activity starts in 1 second tops, this theory I tested out two different apps and I can confirm changing the gradle to the older 2.0.0 improves the first time launch performance.

Please note this issue is a little difficult to notice because it happens ONLY after a fresh installation for the FIRST TIME ONLY, from the next sequence of launches or even updates it opens in a short span of time normally.

So is this a known issue or something? cause I cant find anything to resolve this other than downgrade the gradle which I myself came up with.

JFYI - I used JDK 8 and target the latest API and use the newest version of everything(now except for the gradle of course).

Comment: Here is the post by google developer on g+: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Z1Wwainpjhd

Comment: @KevalPatel sorry you are giving me a link which tells how to effectively use cold start time, I'm already doing that, the problem here is different and your answer is not in context, the cold start time is too long in gradle 2.1.2 and almost negligible in 2.0.0, this is the problem.

Comment: Use one APK from the old gradle version and one from the new gradle version and decompile them using apktool. Then perform a diff on the directories and see what has changed.